# How to bind asynchrounously a ArrayList<Object> to a ListView?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-loader

I'm trying to bind some data to a ListView but instead of being data direct from the tables of a database I have already worked data. So what happens is that I do a query, do some calculations and populate an ArrayList and then need to have this data binded to an ListView.

What I thought at first was having this query and calculations inside the onCreateLoader so every time my database changed it would be notified and my array would be repopulated followed by the refresh of the ListView.

My problem is being the implementation of the necessary changes in the Loader and the ArrayAdapter. The Loader I'm used to is the CursorLoader + a SimpleCursorAdapter so I can only use Cursors Objects.

How can I proceed? Where should I look for a solution of this kind?

Thanks

Comment: This is the problem. I'm still thinking how to do it. I don't have a code yet because it wouldn't work.
I used the SimpleCursorAdapter + CursorLoader in other pages, but it is not the case in this one because I need to do calculations with an array os values before putting it in the Adapter.

Comment: I would suggest to start with the Android sample `ApiDemos` they have more than 10 list examples and take it from there